# Multiple Model Seralizer

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class SongsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
artist_name = Artist.objects.name
genre_name = Genre.objects.name
class Meta:
    model = Song

    fields = [
        'pk',
        'album',
        'art',
        'title',
        'song',
        'artist',
        'slug',
        'genre',
    ]
    read_only_fields = ['id']
```

Serializer.py

So have 3 type of model classes and each one have some foreign key relation

```
class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    song = models.FileField(upload_to='songs')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,default='')
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

JSON response of the API is:

```html
{pk: 1, album: 1, art: "http://localhost:8000/media/art_music/pp_PAgznjI.jpg", title: "Test", song: "http://localhost:8000/media/songs/Daaru_Band_-_Mankirt_Aulakh_DJJOhAL.Com_CtS7TAv.mp3", …}
```

Instead of showing Artist and Genre as 1, it should show the name of the Album, Artist and Genre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use also serializers for your ForeignKey they also need to be serialized. If you forget that only the `id` of the `ForeignKey` will be serialized.

```
class SongsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        artist = ArtistSerializer()
        class Meta:
        model = Song

        fields = [
            'pk',
            'album',
            'art',
            'title',
            'song',
            'artist',
            'slug',
            'genre',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['id']


class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       fields = [
            'pk',  
            'name'
        ]
```